# Entity Framework 4.0 CTP5 ComplexType why and what for do i need it?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

Actually haven't found the answer for this one.

What for and why do i need a complex type in ef4?

Please give a code example in c# it will be more than appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information might be better suited to fit into a complex type. For example given that you have a product type, which contains some information about it's width, height and depth. You could create a property/column for each one of them. Or just create a single property using a complex-type which is mapped to multiple columns:

```
public class Dimensions
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Depth { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Dimensions Dimensions { get; set; }
}
```

Your ´Products´ table might actually look like this: Id, Name, Width, Height, Depth; but you get a much nicer object.

Also complex-types can be used to solve some problems with the EF and custom user types. But I won't get into that now.

Comment: "Also complex-types can be used to solve some problems with the EF and custom user types. But I won't get into that now." Why????

Comment: Apparently you just got started with complex-types, I didn't want to you confuse you. There are some examples, where you can use complex-type to fake enums or an IXmlSerializable.

Comment: Thank you, would appreciate if you would show me how to use them.

Comment: @IamStalker: What approach do you use? Model-First, Database-First or Code-First?

Comment: I use CodeOnly etc... On existing DB i use Code Only approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use complex types for example for an address property on person.

Your objects look like this.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Line3 { get; set; }
    }
```

You database has the following table.

Person: Name, Address_Line1, Address_Line2, Address_Line3

This way you can code in a OOP way.

I use it mostly for a one to one relation kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't be better if i use a regular class to so? It's any way a 1 : 1 relation ship?